# How to convert Varchar into Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a Trial Balance Report ,

and i have a field named : 'PERIOD_NAME' which stores the accounting period name,

and my question is : is it possible to convert the 'PERIOD_NAME' which is a "VARCHAR2" into "DATE"
in order to sort the months ASC , To give me this Result

```
jan- 16
jan- 17
Feb- 16
Feb- 17
```

Comment: If you convert to date, `Feb- 16` will be before `jan- 17` so you won't get this result.

Comment: What do those names represent?  If it's a year-month, then you have to decide what date.

Comment: The function to convert a `varchar2` into a `date` is [`to_date`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions219.htm). What isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

Use `TO_DATE( string, format_model, nls_settings )` assuming your `PERIOD_NAME` is like `jan-17` (but it is unclear from your question what the exact format is):

```
SELECT TO_DATE( period_name, 'MON-YY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English' )
FROM   your_table;
```

If you want to sort by month then year then you can use `EXTRACT` to get the month or year and sort on that:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT TO_DATE( period_name, 'MON-YY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English' ) AS period_date
  FROM   your_table
)
ORDER BY EXTRACT( MONTH FROM period_date ),
         EXTRACT( YEAR FROM period_date );
```

Comment: One thought: To avoid one call to EXTRACT per row, the second order criterion could simply be `period_date`. Indeed, rows are already ordered by month, so following that with ordering by `period_date` will simply further order by year.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are after? Basically, I have used to_date to convert the period name to a date and then extracted the month and year separately to use in the sort. Hope this helps!

**Data**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table 
(
  col1 VARCHAR2(10)
)  ;
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('jan- 16');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('jan- 17');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Feb- 16');
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('Feb- 17');
```

**Solution**

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM my_table t
 ORDER BY to_char(to_date(col1, 'mon- yy'), 'mm'),
          to_char(to_date(col1, 'mon- yy'), 'yy')
```

**Result**

*COL1*

jan- 16

jan- 17

Feb- 16

Feb- 17